# Django uses 'login' twice. How should I resolve the conflict when importing?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-authentication

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

If I require both "login"s, what is the ideal thing to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `as`. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as login_view
```